# How to get all rapidshare and their sub domain ip-address?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, subdomain

How to get all rapidshare and their sub domain ip-address?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could get that information at a given point in time, it would likely soon become out of date.  That information probably changes fairly regularly.

I assume you're trying to block RapidShare in your organization?  Why not just block via the DNS names?

Comment: No, i try to reroute its link on Linux. So i think it must using ip address.